# How to create this 'for each loop' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

Given:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end
```

Upon receipt of a JSON file that includes the author's articles, I'd like to destroy the articles that are in the database for the author, but not included in the JSON file. How can I create this 'for each loop'?

```
article_collection = @author.articles.all
unless article_collection.blank?
  article_collection.each do |article_from_collection|
    # How can I check on the next line if it's id is included in the params?
    if article_from_collection.arti_id "is not part of" params[:author][:articles_attributes]
      article_from_collection.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

How can I check on the 5th line, on basis of `arti_id` which is also included in the params, whether the article with that `arti_id` exists in the JSON input?

Should I perhaps build a collection of `arti_id`s in the parameters and then use `.include?` to see for each article in the DB, if it is in this collection?

I tried the two lines below. The first returns `false` irrespective whether the article is included in the json or not. The second line returns the error `TypeError Exception: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`.

```
if params[:author][:articles_attributes].include? article_from_collection.arti_id
if params[:author][:articles_attributes][:arti_id].include? article_from_collection.arti_id
```

`params[:author]` returns something like:

```
{ "some_other_attributes"=>[ {"key"=>"value", ...},
                             {...} ],
  "articles_attributes"=>  [ {"arti_id"=>"string-id", "other_attributes"=>"value", ...},
                             {"arti_id"=>"string-id", "other_attributes"=>"value", ...} ]
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of how the params[:author] is like?

Comment: I added it to the OP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with an ActiveRecord query

```
article_ids = params[:author][:article_attributes].map do |attrs|
  attrs[:arti_id]
end

@author.articles.where.not(id: article_ids).destroy_all
```

This will destroy all articles for the author whose ids are not in the article attributes you've been given.

If you're confused about the query, it simply creates a `NOT IN` query which filters out the articles passed in and then destroys the ones that are left over.

Comment: Thanks, would this still work in case `article_ids` is `nil` (no articles at all)? Or would the last line then throw an error?

Comment: If article_ids is empty, as map always returns an array, it will simply destroy all of the articles for the author.

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can first map out all the `arti_id` in a separate array variable, and then use the [`include?` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) or the [`exclude?` method](http://apidock.com/rails/String/exclude%3F) to check if a particular id is in the array.

*Example:*

```
article_ids = params[:author][:articles_attributes].map{ |art_attr| art_attr[:arti_id] }
```

and then in the loop: ( for using the `include?` method )

```
article_collection = @author.articles.all
unless article_collection.blank?
  article_collection.each do |article_from_collection|
    # This is how you can handle it...
    unless article_ids.include? article_from_collection.arti_id 
      article_from_collection.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

or if you will prefer using `exclude`?

```
article_collection = @author.articles.all
unless article_collection.blank?
  article_collection.each do |article_from_collection|
    # This is how you can handle it...
    if article_ids.exclude? article_from_collection.arti_id 
      article_from_collection.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like the following:

```
article_collection = @author.articles.all
params_article_ids = params[:author][:articles_attributes].collect{ |article_attrs| article_attrs[:arti_id]}

article_collection.reject{ |art| present_article_ids.include?(art.id)}.each(&:destroy)
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume your params[:author][:articles_attributes] holds hashes of article attributes where each of them has an arti_id.

At first I would return all article ids of the author:

```
all_article_ids = @author.articles.pluck(:arti_id)
```

Second, I collect all arti_ids from your article attributes you want to keep save:

```
ids = params[:author][:articles_attributes].map{|attr| attr.arti_id}
```

Now there are two arrays of ids. I subtract the "ids" array from the "all_article_ids" and I get a new array of ids, which are not in the "ids" array. These are the ids of "all_article_ids", which should be destroyed.

```
@author.articles.destroy(all_article_ids - ids)
```

Is this what fits your needs?